# How to cancel the count between 24th and 25th member of the array

Tags: python

I currently have the following function that counts the variation in an array if it does not vary to 0. I want to add a restriction that cancels the count between every 24th and 25th member of the array. The array accounts for 24 hours period and I don´t want to count the variation between days. There are lots of days so it needs to happen every 24th index.

```
def count_pump_switches(arr): 
    count=0
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        if arr[i-1] != arr[i] and arr[i]!=0:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel"?  Stop and return the total for the first day?  Or do you want to return totals for multiple days?

Comment: totals for multiple days, without counting the variation between the last hour of the day and the first of the following day

Comment: @DaveCosta if I want to count for each day (24 hour period) and store it in a list, what changes would I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to cancel the 24th and the 25th element (at index 23 and 24), periodically every 24 element, you can add the condition checking with (i % 24 != 0). So the code will be:

```
def count_pump_switches(arr): 
count=0
for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    if arr[i-1] != arr[i] and arr[i]!=0 and i % 24 != 0:
        count+=1
return count
```